# Update node to v12 on ubuntu

Tags: loopbackjs

I want to update my node to version greater than v10 but i still get v9.11.2. I tried this commands

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

and i am still on v9.11.2
i also remove and reinstall but no change.
With **n** :`n latest` the answer it's also v9.11.2
with `sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade nodejs`
the response is: **your version is up to date**

I really need v10 and greater for my loopback project

Answer (score 32, accepted):

First remove nodejs using,

> sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove nodejs

Then after,
if curl is not installed then run the below command

> sudo apt-get install curl

Then after run the below 2 commands,

> curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo -E bash -
>
> sudo apt-get install -y nodejs

Comment: I still have v9.11.2 after all this

Comment: @gildaskevin this command worked for me.. `sudo apt-get install -y nodejs`

Comment: I followed the steps, but I still have version 10. Trying to get version 12 .

Comment: Same issue for me.  It still install Node 10.

Answer (score 3):

You can install the latest version from non Official Ubuntu repos.

First you can use a PPA (personal package archive) maintained by NodeSource.

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x -o nodesource_setup.sh
```

Change the permission to 755 or 764 and run the file

```
sudo bash nodesource_setup.sh
```

The PPA will be added to your configuration and now you can install the Node.js package...

```
sudo apt install nodejs
node -v
```

v16.10.0

Comment: No need to chmod the downloaded file - simply invoking using bash will suffice.  Also, as of 2024, setup_20.x is the LTS version of node.js.   (reader from the future - node will let you know what the current LTS version is)

Answer (score 0):

## [Node Version Manager](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)

I have been through all of the ways to do this, and as of 2022, I can tell you that the best way is to use **NVM**. You can get the free opensource version managment tool freely by visiting the repository at the link above (click on the title), or you can simply use the following command, which auto-updates your `$HOME/.bashrc` configuration. Because your `.bashrc` is updated, there is no need to do anything, beyond the curl command below, to install **NVM**.

---

##### NVM via Curl:

- ###### *`curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash`*

---

###### Alternatively, if you prefer `wget`, use the following...

---

##### NVM via Wget

- ###### *`wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash`*

---

At this point you can preform the following commands.

If you don't have NPM you can start with this command

###### `~$> nvm install-latest-npm`

The above will upgrade to the latest **NPM** version for the current node version.

If you have NPM, or already installed NPM as shown above, get the latest node version with the command below.

###### `~/$> nvm install node`

the above installs the newest version of node.

If you want the long term support version instead, preform this command

###### `~/$> install --lts`

you can switch between the two by using the following:

###### `~/$> use node`    -or-   `~/$> nvm use --lts`

you can also use...

###### `~/$> install 10.1.2`

To install a different version, just replace `10.1.2` with the version you want

There is one hiccup that occurs when choosing to use **NVM** *(Node Ver Manager)* as your method for installing **Node.js**, however; it is easily dealt with.

###### On an Important Side Note:

> ###### *Many developers struggle with the "hiccup" that I am referencing. Its not a difficult thing to fix, but it is important to know how to fix it so your Linux Operating System & Commands work as you intend for them to (and as you desire for them to).*

---

### THE NVM HICCUP

---

##### Step #1

When **NVM** updates & installs **Node.js** & **NPM**, the versions that you install, each get placed into the directory @ `"$HOME/.nvm/versions/node"`.

The problem with this is even though you use **NVM** to upgrade **Node.js**, when you use the command `node -v` the console will print the old version, because your binaries haven't been updated with a symbolic link to the new node version.

##### SOLUTION, Adding upgraded Symbolic Link for Node.js

---

I suggest that you look at that directory if you have already used **NVM** to install **Node.js** &/or **NPM**, using the common cmd...

###### `~/$> ls ~/.nvm`

###### `~/$> ls ~/.nvm/versions`

###### `~/$> ls ~/.nvm/versions/node`

###### `~/$> ls ~/.nvm/versions/npm` (use this only if you have NPM versions)

Listing the directories will familiarize you with your **Linux OS**, with **NVM**, & with **Node.js**.

Inside the directory, you should have found each version you installed of **Node.js** & **NPM**.

##### Step #2

---

###### *Currently the node version is 17.5.0 at the time of writing this.*

---

...so, at the time of writing this, when I install the latest **Node Version** I will perform the next step like this.

###### `~/$> cd ~/.nvm/versions/node/17.5.0`

You will want to replace `17.5.0` with what ever version your working with.

You should now have your consoles cmdLine pointed at the current **Node.js** version's directory that you installed using **NVM**.

###### use `~/$> ls .` to veiw the contents.

You should see a `bin` dir listed, go ahead and use:

###### `~/$> cd bin` from within the nvm-node directory...

Alternatively you can use the following from whatever directory your in

###### `~/$> cd ~/.nvm/versions/node/17.5.0/bin`

Once inside your nodes `bin` directory, use `~/$> ls -1 .` \

You should see a couple symbolic links, and a node executable. In my terminal (which uses the standard ANSI Linux color scheme) the `node` executable is highlighted green.

It will simply be called `node`, but it won't be a directory.

preform this command

#### `~/$> sudo cp ./node /usr/bin/node`

That copies the executable, which cannot be linked using the `ln -s ...` command into your binaries.

Now if you use `node -v` you will have the latest version.

---